# Return proper errors from API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api-design

I have the following #create method:

```
def create
    begin
      @order = @api_user.orders.create!(order_params)
      render :json => @order, :only => [:id], :status => :created, :location => @order
    rescue
      render :json => {}, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    end
end
```

However, I am using a generalistic approach for the rescue. If the order could not be created because one of the passed fields failed the validation, I would like to let the user know about that. So, if the creation of the order raised this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Description1 is too long (maximum is 35 characters)
```

What is the proper way of catching and letting the API user know about it?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is make use of a light API library like rocketpants (https://github.com/Sutto/rocket_pants)

in which case, the method you want could be written like this:

```
def create
   if @order = @api_user.orders.create!(order_params)
      expose @order
   else
    error! :bad_request, :metadata => {:error_description => "#{@order.errors.full_messages}"}
   end
end
```

This is assuming you have set the `@api_user` instance variable earlier somewhere. Also, the gem uses Active Model Serializers (https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to serialize the `@order` into JSON, so you can always customize the output to your liking by creating a basic serializer, look at the github page for more info :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
def create
  @order = @api_user.orders.build(order_params)
  if @order.save
    render :json => @order, 
      :only => [:id], :status => :created, :location => @order
  else
    render :status => :unprocessable_entity, 
      :json => {:errors => @order.errors.full_messages}
  end
end
```

You'll get back an array of errors in the JSON

Comment: Actually, if I do @order.errors I get ``NoMethodError: undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass``

Comment: so @api_user.orders.create!(order_params) raised and didn't return anything.

Comment: That's correct. It raised an error, but didn't set @order.

Comment: I re-wrote it to use build and save, which will give you an @order